# Ant problem with Drip Coffee Machine

Tags: cleaning, ants

This is a problem that most probably occurs in tropical countries like where I live, but I basically have the following issue.

I have [Breville Grind Control](https://www.breville.com/us/en/products/coffee/bdc650.html) coffee maker and while it is very techy and is practically a semiautomatic coffee maker, it is a pain in the ass to clean.

On top of that I always have some very very tiny ants in the area around my coffee makers. In the case of the espresso machine they just die in the water tank, but don't cause anymore issues.

But recently I realized that the drip coffe maker (Grind Control) has been converted to an anthouse.

I tried using sodium bicarbonate and water (the machine needed cleaning by now) and I thought well that would clean the ant problem, but the machine has a lot of crevices and they seem to be in many other places so the cleaning thing didn't remove all of them.

I don't want to use pesticide near my coffee, but I am also afraid if I try dismantling the coffee maker I won't be able to put it back together correctly.

Is there anything I can do to get rid of those ants? It would help for the espresso maker too cause they have massive suicides in the water tank.

Comment: Vinegar. It's a mild acid, so don't wreck anything with it. Given enough time I expect it would even etch stainless steel.

Comment: Yes, it was just to clean the interior, but the critters are in all possible crevices and they are tiny, like a regular ant is at most 2mm long. I don't want to throw the coffe machine because it's kind of expensive but I also don't want my coffee to have ant corpses :(

Comment: The name suggests it might have a built in grinder. Any dry parts like that are not going to be cleaned by wet cleaning processes, and could be ruined by trying

Comment: You first need to find out exactly what type of ants they are. If they're Pharaohs, for instance, every time you attack them the colony will bud & spread… bad news. Instead you should lay hormone bait traps & they will just naturally age & die, unable to breed.

Comment: boric acid, aka roach powder. you can get it as a single-ingredient formulation. Make a bait and put next to the maker. It's non-toxic to mammals, they add it to toothpaste and LD50 is the same as salt.

Comment: empty all water and place the coffee maker into a freezer for a few days

Comment: @Tetsujin it does look like it, I am going to look for the boric acid thing. So I just put a little bit in a bottle cap next to the coffee maker and wait for them to die off? Will they leave the coffee maker if they start dying or a little dead ant won't affect it.

Comment: @dandavis that looks reasonable, I'm gonna look for it.

Comment: @jsotola it might work once, but they will most definitely recolonize it a couple of days after I take it out.

Comment: They sell it at box stores in a liter-size squeeze bottle. Look for bait recipes online, i find water with bacon grease, oats, and brown sugar to work well around here, but different ants have different tastes. You only want about 10-20% BA for maximum effectiveness; the ants must survive long enough to nurse larvae to eradicate the nest.  You can try pre-mixed traps with boric acid (terro, combat, etc), but I don't think they work as well. It's also great for athlete's foot and other fungal problems, and it makes paper fireproof. I love the stuff.

Comment: Everybody seems to be up on the boric acid/poisoning idea… but that doesn't work for pharaohs, hence my earlier warning. Trying to poison pharaohs gets you… more pharaohs - all the surviving workers turn as if by magic into queens and spread like wildfire. Been there, done that, learned the lesson.

Comment: @Tetsujin I think I mixed up things then, what would be a hormonal bait trap?

Comment: Have a look at this for some background, official UK pest control - https://bpca.org.uk/News-and-Blog/Pest-watch/bpca-pestwatch-pharaoh-ants - They don't advertise brands, but I found a US equivalent that does - https://www.thepestadvice.com/pharaoh-ants/ [In the UK, some local councils will offer this service & treatment for free. It might be worth seeing if your local authority has something similar.]

Comment: @Tetsujin I live in Mexico, so this type of info is not easily accessible, I'd have to investigate a little bit.

Comment: Ant problem with Drip Coffee Machine *with integral grinder that I leave filled and sitting on the counter*. - Grounds and the grinder go back in an upper cabinet. You're leaving a medium out for them; there's no nutritional value to coffee. They're after a house not your coffee. - Don't have to fight a losing war against ants if they don't want to be there.

Comment: @Mazura true, but they could find better spots :D also, the machine is made like that. It's not particularly comfortable to be disarming it everytime I want to make a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

To kill: Boric acid + whatever bait they like.

To prevent: In my time in the jungle; I put anything I didn't want covered by ants/kissing bugs on stands and put the stands in water.

Comment: As for the water option it is a little complicated to put a coffee maker in water even if I put it on a stand :D